# Toggle Renaming a File without checking if it exists in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, toggle, file-rename

Non programmer trying to toggle renaming a file from a vb.net form without checking if it exists. Have done this with simple batch file. Would like to to know if it is possible in vb.net without needing to check if file exists. Also do not want to use toggle control, want to use button control as UI preference.
Code used in batch file:

```
set ADDON_PATH="P:\MyPath\MySubFolder\"
set ADDON_NAME="myfile.dll"
set DISABLE_NAME="myfile.bak"
cd /d %ADDON_PATH%
Ren %ADDON_NAME% %DISABLE_NAME% 2> nul || ren %DISABLE_NAME% %ADDON_NAME% 2> nul
```

Partial code here for vb.net using button, **not toggle** button

```
Private Sub PlayVanilla(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        If Button11.Text = "Vanilla Mode" Then
            Button11.Text = "Modded Game"
            Button11.ForeColor = Color.Green
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("P:\MyPath\MySubFolder\myfile.dll", "myfile.bak")
        Else
            Button11.Text = "Vanilla Mode"
            Button11.ForeColor = Color.Red
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("P:\MyPath\MySubFolder\myfile.bak", "myfile.dll")
        End If

    End Sub
```

I haven't tried the code above because obviously the file could be in either state, myfile.bak or myfile.dll. So the question is, do i need to check if file exists or can I use a construct as I did in the batch file. One final note, this file always exists and I'm the only user so 0% risk of it not being there. The batch file works simply and perfectly but I don't want to run the batch file from VB form, looking for VB solution. Thank you.

Comment: Should be fine to check if the file exists first. Any reason not to?

Comment: No reason not to. Just curious. as I'm very new to VB.net and definitely not a programmer, as to whether this is possible given the simplicity and elegance of the batch file method. If not, will definitely check for if file exists.

Comment: Just had a thought. Perhaps with the iif function. Will test.

Comment: Bluntly,  _I haven't tried the code above_, then why are you asking here?  Try it and see what happens.  There are many strategies to attempt renaming files but really the best idea is to make your system as robust as possible and do as much as possible to avoid problems so would 100% recomend checking the file exists AND available (as in not locked by another process etc) before attempting any sort of file handling.

Comment: File exist it is then.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find solution matching the batch file example, so will test for file exists. In passing, this isn't an enterprise solution -probability of the file being locked by another process is exactly zero. Additionally, there is 100% probability the file exists in one of two name states. However I understand and appreciate the robustness comments and accept them. Thanks.

```vb
Imports System.IO

If Directory.Exists("P:\MyPath\Myfolder\Myfile.dll") Then ...
```